# How to calculate ratio of two side automatically?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,amsmath,amssymb,pst-calculate}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(7,6)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,90,-45}](0,0){B}(2,5){A}(6,0){C}
\pstProjection[PosAngle=-90]{B}{C}{A}[H]
\pcline(A)(H)
\pcline(B)(C)
\psGetDistanceAB[xShift=-8,yShift=3](B)(C){BC}
\psGetDistanceAB[xShift=2](A)(H){AH}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

1. What is the purpose of {BC} and {AH}? (Until now, I don't know the usage of it. Can you give me a simple sample?)
2. How to calculate AH/BC without using \psGetDistanceAB?

Comment: What do you want  to calculate this ratio for? *A priori*, I suppose it's not to discover the obvious answer…

Comment: @Bernard I have this idea from "draw an inscribed squares in the triangle" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AH` and `BC` are node names:

```
\psGetDistanceAB[xShift=-8,yShift=3](B)(C){BC} 
\psGetDistanceAB[xShift=2](A)(H){AH}    
\psdots[dotstyle=x,dotscale=1.5](BC)(AH)
```

[image]

The get the side of the square you have to calculate its side. It is done on PostScript Level, the reason why you have to use `latex`-> `dvips`-> `ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(7,6)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,90,-45}](0,0){B}(2,5){A}(6,0){C}
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](A)(B)(C)
\pstProjection[PosAngle=-90]{B}{C}{A}[H]
\pcline(A)(H)
\pcline(B)(C)
\psGetDistanceAB[xShift=-8,yShift=3](B)(C){BC} 
\psGetDistanceAB[xShift=2](A)(H){AH}    
\psdots[dotstyle=x,dotscale=1.5](BC)(AH)
\pnode(! % Calculate the side of the square
  \psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{H}\psGetNodeCenter{B}\psGetNodeCenter{C}
  A.y H.y sub /Height exch def
  C.x B.x sub /Width exch def
  Height dup Width div 1 add div % AH/(AH/AB + 1)
  H.y add H.x exch % x=a+H.y; y=H.y 
  ){a}
\pnode[1,0](a){a1}
\psdots[linecolor=red](a)(a1)
\pstInterLL[PointName=none]{B}{A}{a}{a1}{BA1}
\pstInterLL[PointName=none]{C}{A}{a}{a1}{CA1}
\pspolygon*[opacity=0.3,linecolor=blue](BA1)(CA1)(CA1|H)(BA1|H)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a solution which works for all given points of a triangle you have to
check first which side of the triangle should be the base. Otherwise it wonn't
work. See this animation:

[image]

Comment: I still need the time to understand your answer.

Comment: Until now, I can talk, my idea is: I want to calculate AH/BC on PostScript level and the result of it used as a number, specifically, \psline{->}(0,0)(! 0 xxx) with xxx=AH/BC. If you understand, please to give a example.

Comment: that is already present in my answer! `\psline[linecolor=blue](0,0)(! 0
     \psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{H}\psGetNodeCenter{B}\psGetNodeCenter{C}
    A.y H.y sub C.x B.x sub div)`

Comment: But, can we use \pstVerb for it? (I fail with \pstVerb)

Comment: no, but you can define a dummy node, for example a, which itself saves the value (here as `/REL`) which can then used later: `\pnode(!\psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{H}\psGetNodeCenter{B}\psGetNodeCenter{C}
  A.y H.y sub C.x B.x sub div /REL exch def 0 REL){a}%
 \psline[linecolor=blue](0,0)(! REL dup add REL)`

Comment: So, we **only** have _2_ number within \pnode(! ..... one two){<name>}? Unfortunately, I can't use \pstVerb ...

Comment: With `(! ...)` you can do what you want, but at the end of the PostScript part there must be _two_ numbers for x y.

Comment: Sorry but, a quibble: I try google "PostScript" and see **Stable release: PostScript 3 / 1997; 22 years ago**...PostScipt is outdated (I think so) ... and PSTricks (in the future) has same? ;-( You can tell me a bit about your thinking.

Comment: Every printer has a PostScript driver. PDF is a subset of PostScript ...

Comment: Why do we still use pstricks97.tex together with **pstricks.tex** ?

Comment: Nobody uses `pstricks97`! It is only for some historical reason there.